# Is there a "Hello, World" GNU-like sample project for libraries?

Tags: c, gnu

[GNU Hello](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/) is GNU's example project for best practices, coding standards, internationalization, configuration automation, etc.

Is there a similar project that targets libraries? I realize GNU Hello can be used in that way, but would I be missing some library-specific practices?

I've also searched for good tutorials on this topic, and the [Program Library HOWTO](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/) seems to be the most appropriate one out there. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid (like the plague) the GNU coding style. It's not only annoying to write, it's especially annoying to come across in the wild. Thankfully, one doesn't come across it much in serious code.

Comment: Yeah, it does look atrocious, but I suppose consistency trumps looks here, if you're doing a project for GNU itself. However, I'm more looking for `autoconf` boiler plate and such.

Comment: Really, stay away from GNU coding style unless you're writing code for which you plan to assign copyright to the FSF as an official part of "GNU". It's the worst coding style out there, and GNU practice for using autoconf, etc. is pretty atrocious too (multiple nested levels of configure scripts getting run *after* you finish running the main configure and type `make`? Gimme a break..) I'd look to other places for best practices.

Comment: And regarding consistency, very little free software outside of the official GNU project uses the GNU coding style or practices... probably because most people immediately gag at seeing it.

Comment: https://stylecop.codeplex.com/ ftw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project called [libabc: shared library skeleton](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/kay/libabc.git) created by Lennart Poettering:

> To make things easy we have put together an example skeleton library we dubbed libabc, whose README file includes all our points in terse form.

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/libabc.html

Answer (score 1):

The following are some guidelines that I regularly bring up. I'm not entirely sure how helpful they'll be:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/

Otherwise, I just try to match what I see. Looking at the above style guides should give you a good indication of what consistencies to look for and attempt to match in your code.

**Edit:**

I should clarify, the above guides are not specific to GNU, but might help you find consistencies such as naming schemes or tab/spacing guides.

Answer (score 0):

I read through the GNU manual and found a short example that I think would get you to a good start:

[Straight from the manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#system_002eh)

```
/* hello.c -- print a greeting message and exit.

    Copyright (C) 1992, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002,
    2005, 2006, 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
    any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
    Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.  */

 #include <config.h>
 #include "system.h"

 /* String containing name the program is called with.  */
 const char *program_name;

 static const struct option longopts[] =
 {
   { "greeting", required_argument, NULL, 'g' },
   { "help", no_argument, NULL, 'h' },
   { "next-generation", no_argument, NULL, 'n' },
   { "traditional", no_argument, NULL, 't' },
   { "version", no_argument, NULL, 'v' },
   { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 }
 };

 static void print_help (void);
 static void print_version (void);

 int
 main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   int optc;
   int t = 0, n = 0, lose = 0;
   const char *greeting = NULL;

   program_name = argv[0];

   /* Set locale via LC_ALL.  */
   setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

 #if ENABLE_NLS
   /* Set the text message domain.  */
   bindtextdomain (PACKAGE, LOCALEDIR);
   textdomain (PACKAGE);
 #endif

   /* Even exiting has subtleties.  The /dev/full device on GNU/Linux
      can be used for testing whether writes are checked properly.  For
      instance, hello >/dev/full should exit unsuccessfully.  On exit,
      if any writes failed, change the exit status.  This is
      implemented in the Gnulib module "closeout".  */
   atexit (close_stdout);

   while ((optc = getopt_long (argc, argv, "g:hntv", longopts, NULL)) != -1)
     switch (optc)
       {
       /* One goal here is having --help and --version exit immediately,
          per GNU coding standards.  */
       case 'v':
         print_version ();
         exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
         break;
       case 'g':
         greeting = optarg;
         break;
       case 'h':
         print_help ();
         exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
         break;
       case 'n':
         n = 1;
         break;
       case 't':
         t = 1;
         break;
       default:
         lose = 1;
         break;
       }

   if (lose || optind < argc)
     {
       /* Print error message and exit.  */
       if (optind < argc)
         fprintf (stderr, _("%s: extra operand: %s\n"),
         program_name, argv[optind]);
       fprintf (stderr, _("Try `%s --help' for more information.\n"),
                program_name);
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

   /* Print greeting message and exit. */
   if (t)
     printf (_("hello, world\n"));

   else if (n)
     /* TRANSLATORS: Use box drawing characters or other fancy stuff
        if your encoding (e.g., UTF-8) allows it.  If done so add the
        following note, please:

        [Note: For best viewing results use a UTF-8 locale, please.]
     */
    printf (_("\
 +---------------+\n\
 | Hello, world! |\n\
 +---------------+\n\
 "));

   else
     {
       if (!greeting)
         greeting = _("Hello, world!");
       puts (greeting);
     }

   exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }


 
 /* Print help info.  This long message is split into
    several pieces to help translators be able to align different
    blocks and identify the various pieces.  */

 static void
 print_help (void)
 {
   /* TRANSLATORS: --help output 1 (synopsis)
      no-wrap */
         printf (_("\
 Usage: %s [OPTION]...\n"), program_name);

   /* TRANSLATORS: --help output 2 (brief description)
      no-wrap */
   fputs (_("\
 Print a friendly, customizable greeting.\n"), stdout);

   puts ("");
   /* TRANSLATORS: --help output 3: options 1/2
      no-wrap */
   fputs (_("\
   -h, --help          display this help and exit\n\
   -v, --version       display version information and exit\n"), stdout);

   puts ("");
   /* TRANSLATORS: --help output 4: options 2/2
      no-wrap */
   fputs (_("\
   -t, --traditional       use traditional greeting format\n\
   -n, --next-generation   use next-generation greeting format\n\
   -g, --greeting=TEXT     use TEXT as the greeting message\n"), stdout);

   printf ("\n");
   /* TRANSLATORS: --help output 5 (end)
      TRANSLATORS: the placeholder indicates the bug-reporting address
      for this application.  Please add _another line_ with the
      address for translation bugs.
      no-wrap */
   printf (_("\
 Report bugs to <%s>.\n"), PACKAGE_BUGREPORT);
 }


 
 /* Print version and copyright information.  */

 static void
 print_version (void)
 {
   printf ("hello (GNU %s) %s\n", PACKAGE, VERSION);
   /* xgettext: no-wrap */
   puts ("");

   /* It is important to separate the year from the rest of the message,
      as done here, to avoid having to retranslate the message when a new
      year comes around.  */
   printf (_("\
 Copyright (C) %s Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n\
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later\
 <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\n\
 This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\n\
 There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.\n"),
               "2007");
 }
```

Comment: The OP wants a similar example for *libraries*